# @startup and @postConstruct not called at payara startup

Tags: java, maven, java-ee-7, payara-micro

I am developing a JEE application and I want to do some migration when the application starts. Actually, I am using `payara-micro` with Docker as a server.  For an unknown reason, this code is never executed.

Here is my code :

```
@Singleton
@Startup
public class FlywayMigration {


    @PostConstruct
    public void startMigration(){
      System.out.println("Starting flyway migration");
    }
}
```

I added the javaee-api as dependency in my pom :

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax</groupId>
        <artifactId>javaee-api</artifactId>
        <version>7.0</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
```

Here is the content of my Dockerfile :

```
FROM payara/micro

COPY ./target/mywebapp.war $DEPLOY_DIR
```

After building and running the docker image, the logs of the application shows that the app started well :

```
Payara Micro URLs
http://5b258e6a441a:8080/mywebapp

'mywebapp' REST Endpoints
 GET    /mywebapp/api/hello
 GET    /mywebapp/api/myresource
```

Can anyone help me find a solution ?

Comment: *For an unknown reason, this code is never executed.* How are you starting up your application?

Comment: Yes, the application starts. I even have some rest web services that are accessible

Comment: @Dmitri . I meant how do you start up the application? Using some command line or IDE configuration?

Comment: Oh ok, I am actually using docker and the war is copied to the container and the deployment is done automatically

Comment: At the bottom of the Payara Micro log file, it gives you a summary of what's deployed. Is that telling you that the app deploys? It would also be useful to see your Dockerfile

Comment: @mike I have updated the questions

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I finally make it work. The problem is that I was using the bad `@Singleton` annotation. Instead of using `@javax.ejb.Singleton` I used to `@javax.inject.Singleton`.